# React hooks: How to conditionally trigger hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

In my React Native app, I have a variable `var1` that gets updated 10 times, and on the 10th time another variable `flag` gets set to `true`. I want to trigger `useEffect` on `var1` only when `flag == true`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: add `flag` to the dependency array of the useEffect? (whenever flag changes the useEffect will run)

Comment: I want it to run only when flag is `true` though, not just when it's toggled.

Comment: Then check if it's true in the useEffect otherwise exit, alternatively handle your var1 business at the same time you set flag to true.

Comment: On the first 10 iterations only `var1` will change, so `useEffect()` won't get triggered, but on the next iteration both `var1` and `flag` will change, so `useEffect()` will be triggered, and I should then check within the useEffect callback if `flag` is true?

Comment: That's what you indicated you wanted in your question. Is there something else that causes flag to change? or do you mean you want to trigger on every `var1` change after it reaches 10?

Comment: I'm asking if I understood your suggestion correctly. Ideally `useEffect()` would be triggered only if `flag` were `true`, but this works well too. Feel free to post as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: There's something that will cause flag to be toggled back to false. In this case I don't want the callback to be called. Also, I want the condition on `flag` to just be that it's `true`, not necessarily that it's just been changed to `true`. Checking if it's true/false in the callback is fine, but I was wondering if there were some way I could trigger it on `var1 has changed and flag is true` rather than `var1 has changed and flag has changed`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, I see, then put `var1` in the dependency array and check if `flag` is true. `useEffect(() => {if (flag) {...}}, [var1])`

Comment: Gotcha, this works, thank you! Feel free to post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect({
    if(var1===10){
        setFlag(true)
    }
   },[var1])

useEffect({
    if(flag){
        //write your code here
    }  
},[flag])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.